# Different results in TfLite model vs model before quantization

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I have taken Object Detection model from TF zoo v2,
I took mobilenet and trained it on my own TFrecords
I am using mobilenet because it is often found in the examples of converting it to Tflite and this is what I need because I run it on RPi3.

I am following ideas from the official example [from Sagemaker docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/training-and-deploying-models-using-tensorflow-2-with-the-object-detection-api-on-amazon-sagemaker)
and github you can find [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-tensorflow-object-detection-api)

What is interesting the accuracy done after step 2) training and 3) deploying is pretty nice! My trucks are discovered nicely with the custom trained model.
However, when converted to tflite the **accuracy goes down** no matter if I use `tfliteconvert` tool or using python `tf.lite.Converter`.

What is more, all detections are on borders of images, and usually in the bottom-right corner. Maybe I am not preparing images correctly? Or some misunderstanding of results?

You can check images I uploaded.
https://ibb.co/fSzfZvz
https://ibb.co/0GF101s

What could possibly go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was lacking proper preprocessing of image.
After I have used pipeline config to build detection object which has `preprocess` function I utilized to build tensor before feeding it into `Interpreter`.

```
num_classes = 2
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(pipeline_config)
model_config = configs['model']
model_config.ssd.num_classes = num_classes
model_config.ssd.freeze_batchnorm = True
detection_model = model_builder.build(
      model_config=model_config, is_training=True)
```